# Query to procedure firebird database with PHP

Tags: php, pdo, firebird, procedure

I am creating a web service for a firebase database. I need to execute a query to a procedure firebird. I do this using PHP with PDO in this way (This is my summarized code):

```
$instalacion = $_REQUEST['instalacion'];
$fecha = $_REQUEST['fecha'];
$inicio = date("m/d/Y",strtotime($fecha))." ".$_REQUEST['inicio'];
$fin = date("m/d/Y",strtotime($fecha))." ".$_REQUEST['fin'];

$reserva_annio = 0;
$reserva = 0;
$numero = 0;
$serie = '';

        $annio = date("Y", strtotime($fecha));

        $res=$dbh->query("execute procedure INS_CREA_RESERVA (date('m/d/Y',strtotime($fecha)), $inicio, $fin, $instalacion)

returning_values($reserva_annio, $reserva, $numero, $serie);  ");
```

The procedure in my firebird is working ok, but this query return me this:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:
>   -104 Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -104 Token unknown - line 3, column 25 '0'

This error tells me that the part that is failing is the returning_values line. But in my firebird work fine.

It is possible that I need to install a library in the php.ini or somethins similar? I already activated this: extension=pdo_firebird, but don't work.

Any advice about my mistake? Thanks!

Comment: i don't think this can work - `returning_values($reserva_annio` - it makes no sence for me. To push values back into the application you server should be given variables (LVALUEs in C++ terms), not constants (RVALUEs)! Though splicing values into SQL literal is bad things even for read-only values for a number of reasons. See https://bobby-tables.com/php

Comment: Yes you're right. After researching online, I have found that this can be done with a simpler select query. I put the solution for possible future errors. Thank you!

Comment: i still strongly suggest you against of string splicing! Do use parameters. It is much more predictable and safe.  In particular you would not need all those `date('m/d/Y'` and guess work about text datetime formats of thisor that SQL server. And you would be able to `prepare` frequently used queries, so you can re-run them without recompiling, just changing parameter values.

Comment: The `RETURNING_VALUES` clause is only for use in PSQL (stored procedure code), not in DSQL. Part of the problem is that you're using string-interpolation (which makes your code vulnerable to SQL injection), instead of real parameters.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I just write the sample code in and for clarity I posted it like this. Actually, the query is built under a prepared statement of course.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$dt=date('m/d/Y',strtotime($fecha));
$res=$dbh->query("execute procedure INS_CREA_RESERVA ('$dt', ......
```

Comment: Good catch. Still splicing will hardly work for OUTPUT parameters or will it in PHP ?

Comment: Yes effectively. That has been the hint to find the solution. Thank you!

Comment: Doing this makes the code vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I just write the sample code in and for clarity I posted it like this. Actually, the query is built under a prepared statement of course.

Answer (score 0):

After researching online, I have found that this can be done with a simpler select query. Requesting it to return data is no sense, and with php it can be done with a simple query similar to this:

```
$instalacion = $_REQUEST['instalacion'];
$fecha = $_REQUEST['fecha'];
$inicio = date("m/d/Y",strtotime($fecha))." ".$_REQUEST['inicio'];
$fin = date("m/d/Y",strtotime($fecha))." ".$_REQUEST['fin'];

$res=$dbh->query("select * from INS_CREA_RESERVA($fecha, $inicio, $fin, $instalacion)");
```

Note that the 'Where' clause must be replaced by brackets and pass parameters separated by commas.

Comment: That is, actually, very questionable. In Interbase/Firebird the procedures are either selectable or not-selectable. Selectable ones can return many rows, zero or one or many. And are to be used with `select .... from ` command. Not-selectable do not return any rows and should be called with `execute procedure` command. If you do `execute procedure` on a selectable one - it will try to return one first row and drop others. Calling wrong kind of SP by not matching command is program design error.

Comment: What if SP returns zero rows? i don't remember. It is shaky. What if you do `select` on a not-selectable one? I don't remember exact details too, shaky. So, one of your commands, this one or prior one, was a mistake, was making program behavior less predictable, especially against possibility of running the program with any different Firebird version, past or future.